# Please explain this reputation change?

Tags: support, reputation

Could someone please explain why I lost 1 reputation after downvoting an answer on [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/620310)? Maybe I'm just having a stupid moment?

Comment: The answer you've downvoted likely would be deleted by mods because of **spam**. After the answer deleted, you will get back your 1 'fake internet point' :)

Comment: Lol thanks. It was more curiosity than actually caring about the rep.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you are. You lose a reputation point for downvoting a answer, but its for a good cause.

Its in the what is [reputation page](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Clearly I didn't do a good enough job searching the FAQ. Thank you!

Comment: Actually you don't lose a point anymore for down voting questions, only for down voting answers... The rationale for that is [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

Comment: Ahh, I mixed up the two. Clearly *I* was having a stupid moment too ;p

Comment: I just finished my second espresso and therefore incredibly pedantic :) while it lasts...